# How to set the size of the bootstrap carusel?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, slider

I am trying to make a carousel for website with bootstrap.I want to set the size of the bootstrap carusel.I have 3 Images and i want to make the size of the slider to be width: 100% and height:150px.

Here is the html code only for slider:

```
 <section id="slider">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12">
          <div class="slider_area">
            <!-- Start super slider -->
            <div id="slides">
              <ul class="slides-container">                          
                <li>
                  <img src="img/slider/2.jpg" alt="img" >
                   <div class="slider_caption">
                    <h2>Largest & Beautiful University</h2>
                    <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
                    <a class="slider_btn" href="#">Know More</a>
                  </div>
                  </li>
                   </ul>
              <nav class="slides-navigation">
                <a href="#" class="next"></a>
                <a href="#" class="prev"></a>
              </nav>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

The css for this HTML is

```
#slider{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
.slider_area {
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}
.slider_caption {
  left: 5%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  width: 50%;
}
.slider_right_caption{
  left: 38%;
}
.slider_caption h2 {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 33px;
  background-color: rgba(49, 59, 61, 0.6);
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.slider_caption p {
  background-color: rgba(49, 59, 61, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Varela",sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 10px;
}
.slider_btn {  
  background: rgba(49, 59, 61, 0.6);
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Varela",sans-serif;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 9px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;  
}
.slider_btn:hover,.slider_btn:focus{   
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
.next,.prev{
  display: none !important;  
}
.slider_area:hover .next{
  display: block !important;
}
.slider_area:hover .prev{
  display: block !important;
}
```

I have tried making the following changes to the CSS but No effect.

```
.slider_area > slides-container > img, .slider_area > slides-container > a > img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

The slider area shrinks to the given height and the content goes behind the slider. But Slider size does not change at all.
Please Guide.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want slider to take full width and push other content below or top but not on the sides. First thing I would try is to make slider display as block element.

Currently you do not have Slider as block element and but as inline element. More about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements
You should give it a read, a very helpful when you understand what Block and non block display do and how it behaves.

In your css you have following code, I propose you change it to block and also remove float if possible i.e. no float rule or float:none if needed for some other style elements.

```
    #slider{
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Becomes

```
  #slider{
  float: none;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: If it does not work, you may share your page's url, so I can look into any other issues might be interfering.